# Teradata: Ranking Consecutive Quarters.

Tags: teradata

I have a question. I am running a query where I get a single ID that has multiple quarters they have met certain criteria. I would like to Rank those that have Consecutive Quarters with only looking back 4 quarters.

```
    ID  FISCAL_QTR  Completed_Fiscal_Qtr    RANKING
    5         2016Q2             ?                   9
    5         2016Q3             ?                   8
    5         2016Q4             ?                   7
    5         2017Q1             ?                   6
    5         2017Q2             ?                   5
    5         2017Q3             ?                   4
    5         2018Q1             ?                   3
    5         2018Q3             ?                   2
    5         2018Q4           2018Q3                1
```

This is what I am currently getting. I would like to see that a ranking of 2 for this id based on the fact that they have 2018q4 and 2018q3 and they missed 2018q2.

Comment: I don't get your description. How does the expected result look like and why?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to go about this. I think one of the more powerful ways is using Period [Normalization](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/vym1472240813272.html) which requires switching your `fiscal_qtr` over to a date period.

For instance `2016Q1` would become `PERIOD(DATE '2016-01-01', DATE '2017-04-01')`. Doing this for each record and then normalizing the periods will give you two non-contiguous chunks you can join back to your original periods using `P_INTERSECT` and then run your `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` on that:

```
WITH dates AS
(
    SELECT 
        PERIOD(MIN(cal.calendar_date), NEXT(MAX(calendar_date))) AS qperiod,
        fiscal_qtr
    FROM your_table
        INNER JOIN Sys_Calendar."CALENDAR" cal
            ON SUBSTR(Fiscal_Qtr, 1, 4) = cal.year_of_calendar
            AND SUBSTR(Fiscal_Qtr, 6, 1) = cal.quarter_of_year
    GROUP BY 2
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d1.qperiod ORDER BY d2.qperiod) AS your_rank,
    d2.fiscal_qtr
FROM (SELECT NORMALIZE qperiod FROM dates) d1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dates d2 
        ON d1.qperiod P_INTERSECT d2.qperiod IS NOT NULL
```